# create a login form and change password from hide to visible

Tags: java, visible, jpasswordfield

I'm trying to create a login form and I have some problems at getting the showPassword checkBox work. When showPassword is selected I want the content of the JPasswordField, passwordField, to be visible and when showPassword is not selected I want it to be "hide". I don't understant why my code doesn't work. I write the code this way because I want to implement it in the future as a Model View Controller. I'd prefer not to change any attribute from private in public if possible. Any ideas why this doesn't work? Thanks!

```
package project3;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LogInWindow extends JFrame {
    private Container container = getContentPane();
    private JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("WarehouseApp");
    private JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("USERNAME");
    private JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
    private JTextField userTextField = new JTextField();
    private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    private JButton loginButton = new JButton("LOGIN");
    private JCheckBox showPassword = new JCheckBox("Show Password");
    private JLabel logInAsLabel = new JLabel("LOGIN AS");
    private JComboBox<String> logInAsComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();

    public LogInWindow() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(10, 10, 370, 370);
        this.setName("Login Form");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        container.setLayout(null);

        titleLabel.setBounds(80, -10, 200, 100);
        userLabel.setBounds(50, 80, 100, 30);
        userTextField.setBounds(150, 80, 150, 30);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(50, 130, 100, 30);
        passwordField.setBounds(150, 130, 150, 30);
        logInAsLabel.setBounds(50, 180, 100, 30);
        logInAsComboBox.setBounds(150, 180, 150, 30);
        showPassword.setBounds(150, 220, 150, 30);
        loginButton.setBounds(150, 260, 100, 30);

        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 30);
        titleLabel.setFont(font);
        logInAsComboBox.addItem("ADMIN");
        logInAsComboBox.addItem("CLIENT");
        logInAsComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        container.add(titleLabel);
        container.add(userLabel);
        container.add(passwordLabel);
        container.add(userTextField);
        container.add(passwordField);
        container.add(logInAsLabel);
        container.add(logInAsComboBox);
        container.add(showPassword);
        container.add(loginButton);

    }

    public void showPasswordWhenClicked(ActionListener listenForPassword) {
        showPassword.addActionListener(listenForPassword);
    }

    public boolean getPasswordStatus() {
        if (showPassword.isSelected()==true) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void setPasswordVisible() {
        passwordField.setEchoChar((char) 0);
    }

    public void setPasswordInvisible() {
        passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
    }   
}

package project3;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Controller {

    private LogInWindow theView;

    public Controller(LogInWindow theView) {
        this.theView = theView;

        this.theView.showPasswordWhenClicked(new showPasswordListener());
    }

    public class showPasswordListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (theView.getPasswordStatus()==true) {
                theView.setPasswordVisible();
            } else {
                theView.setPasswordInvisible();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogInWindow logIn = new LogInWindow();
        logIn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: VGR has your answer and you should both up-vote and accept his answer. Some other unrelated notes: avoid using null layouts and `setBounds(...)` as this leads to rigid hard to improve GUI's that often look terrible on other platforms. Also you should use an ItemListener on the JCheckBox rather than an ActionListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not create an instance of `Controller`, so that class’s constructor is never called.  Therefore, `showPasswordWhenClicked` is never called.

Try adding this line to your `main` method:

```
new Controller(logIn);
```